# Why does clicking certain elements in the Elements tab cause them to flash orange and not be selected?

Tags: selection, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes when working in the Elements tab of Chrome's developer tools, I simply can't choose certain elements. Instead, the element (by which I mean the entry in that tab, with a collapse/un-collapse triangle next to it) reacts by flashing orange and remaining unchosen. What does this mean?

I can't find any examples that aren't my own projects (on a private server), so maybe it's some kind of limitation when Google's server can't reach the site? It doesn't seem to go away when I remove scripts, but perhaps extensions are having this effect?

Comment: I haven't experienced that - it seems like a bug. Since you can't share the website you are working on, can you please: 1) try reproducing it on some other publicly available website and sharing URL? or 2) making a video showing what you are describing.

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, same style of flash as the purple that [shows up when elements change](http://devtoolstips.com/post/122033029028/preview-and-edit-cubic-bezier-functions-using). I just got stuck in this after editing rules for a particular node, unsure what caused it though. Sort of like all elements other than the last one you were editing are locked (up/down arrow keys confirm which element is 'locked onto'). Closing/reopening the DevTools pane resolved it for me though.

Comment: Same here on the solution. Even if the orange flash isn't a bug itself, the fact restarting Dev Tools fixes it (even though doing this should make no change to anything) suggests a buggysituation.

Comment: Restarting the Dev Tools process through Shift + ESC still resolves the problem.